# Working with s but gettng segmentation fault ,when i replace `s` with `s1

Tags: c, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    char s[6] = "HELLO";
    printf("s.len= %d,", (int)strlen(s));
    char* s1 = "HELLO";
    printf("s1.len= %d,", (int)strlen(s1));
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] >= 65 && s[i] <= 90)
            s[i] = s[i] + 32;
        ++i;
    }
    printf("Now s =%s\n", s);
}
```

Working with s but getting segmentation fault, when I replace `s` with `s1` ,although both having same length and same word ("HELLO").

Please help me , point out my error, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Though string literals in C has types of non-const character arrays you may not change them. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behaviour.

For example the compiler is allowed to place a string literal in read-only memory or substitute several identical string literals for one string literal.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Variable s1 is defined as a pointer to the first character of a string literal. So you may not use it to change the string literal. This code snip will be invalid

```
while(s1[i]!='\0')
{
    if(s1[i]>=65 && s1[i]<=90)
     s1[i]=s1[i]+32;
    ++i;
}
```

As for this declaration

```
char s[6] = "HELLO";
```

then there is the string literal is used to initialize the array that is allocated separately. Simply characters from the string literal are copied to the elements of the array. You may change the array if it is defined as non-const.

Take into account that in C++ string literals have types of **const** character arrays.

Comment: means s1[0]='k';is invalid.

Comment: can i change the address of s1?? or it will give me some error??

Comment: @m23 You may reassign s1 because it is a non-const object. You might not do this if it were defined as char * const s1 = "HELLO";

Comment: @m23 See one more my post. I cited the corresponding quote from the C Standard.

Answer (score 1):

`char s[6] = "HELLO";` defines a character array containing six characters, initially initialized to the five characters H,E,L,L,O and a null-terminator.

`char *s1 = "HELLO";` defines a pointer to a constant string literal.

Modifying the character array is OK because the array is only initialized with a constant.

Modifying the string literal is not OK because it is a constant, and this is what you are attempting to do by writing `s1[0] = 'k'`.

Answer (score 0):

`char *s1` defines a string literal which you cannot alter. However if that is your intention you need to define `char *s1` through dynamic memory allocation and set it or modify it accordingly.